How do I compare two variables in an NGNIX conf file using the if statement or some other way?
I have a variable say $foo and I need to do a case-insensitive match against a given pattern, but that pattern is also a variable received via a header. If that is true then I set a given variable to 1, which will be used later on. I tried with the following snippet:
set $variable 0;
if ($foo ~* $http_header) {
    set $variable 1;
}

This didn't work. I also tried using ${http_header}, "$http_header", "${http_header}", but none of these worked. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?
P.S. I know there will be a solution with LUA scripts, but we need to avoid using that for the purposes of the project I am working on.

You can't. (without Lua or njs)

All regular expressions from configuration file(s) are being compiled into libpcre/libpcre2 internal representation during nginx startup, so, as already said, you can't do it.

You can concatenate the two variables then verify that the first half matches the second half using a regex.  Is there an easier way in 2024?
set $room "$carpet:$curtains";

if ($room !~* "^(.*):\1$"){
     return 403 '403 - Carpet ${carpet} did not match curtains ${curtains}';
} 

Borrowed from 2011
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,206345,206620

if is still evil in 2024. better approach is to use map

Using maps to compare two dynamic variables ends up moving the same code above into a map.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnhpatton/08f372f9846c80f187d29c2b8c7d7d6e/raw/d0a78b08b2c443a010cfc137d5c30a06851f996b/nginx-compare-two-variables.conf
https://johnhpatton.medium.com/nginx-map-comparison-regular-express-229120debe46

I use following approach to map http_header $host to my custom variable.
In your case it would be something like:
map $http_header $foo {
    "~*{{REGEX_PATTERN}}" "{{FOO_CONTENT}}";
}

You parse the content of your desired http_header with a {{REGEX_PATTERN}} and set your variable {{FOO_CONTENT}} accordingly.
Keep in mind, you can also use map without regex.
Please have a look at following stackoverflow answer, which sums it up really great.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66381679/10891124
Nginx documenatation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html
